# u-boot EFI support for SetVariable runtime service

Tags: u-boot, uefi

For a proof-of-concept project, I have built a linux kernel image with CONFIG_EFI_STUB that I'm launching from a Shell.efi prebooted by u-boot. The environment variables set by the Shell.efi are visible after mounting efivarfs from the linux shell.

```
sh-5.1# mount -t efivarfs efivarfs /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
sh-5.1# cd /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
sh-5.1# mount | grep efivars
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (ro,relatime)
sh-5.1# ls
AuditMode-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
DeployedMode-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
OsIndications-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
OsIndicationsSupported-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
PlatformLang-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
PlatformLangCodes-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
SecureBoot-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
SetupMode-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
TEST2-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
VendorKeys-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
sh-5.1# hexdump TEST2-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
0000000 0007 0000 0022 0048 0049 0022
000000c
```

where TEST2... is an environment variable I set from the Shell.efi.

However, if I try to set a EFI variable from linux (after manually mounting it in read-write mode), it bails out.

```
sh-5.1# mount -o remount,rw -t efivarfs efivarfs /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
sh-5.1# mount | grep efivars
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,relatime)
sh-5.1# printf "\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00" > TESTVAR-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
sh: printf: write error: Invalid argument
```

I do notice that the SetVariable implementation in u-boot's EFI lib is a stub function that returns EFI_UNSUPPORTED.

```
/**
 * efi_set_variable_runtime() - runtime implementation of SetVariable()
 *
 * @variable_name:  name of the variable
 * @vendor:     vendor GUID
 * @attributes:     attributes of the variable
 * @data_size:      size of the buffer with the variable value
 * @data:       buffer with the variable value
 * Return:      status code
 */
static efi_status_t __efi_runtime EFIAPI
efi_set_variable_runtime(u16 *variable_name, const efi_guid_t *vendor,
             u32 attributes, efi_uintn_t data_size,
             const void *data)
{
    return EFI_UNSUPPORTED;
}
```

What are some of the ways to correctly support a functional SetVariable runtime service in such a setup? Are there any pitfalls/considerations that should I be aware of if I go about implementing something from scratch?

I tried adding debug printk()'s in the efi_set_variable_runtime() but that causes a segmentation fault. How do I enable debug logging for runtime services?

Answer (score 3):

At EFI runtime U-Boot does not have any device drivers (except for reboot/poweroff on some boards). It can neither print to the console nor can it store variables anywhere.

One implementation of EFI variables in U-Boot uses the Replay Protected Memory Block (RPMB) of an eMMC for storage. StandaloneMM used as an OP-TEE module implements the necessary logic. See https://u-boot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/develop/uefi/uefi.html#using-op-tee-for-efi-variables.

A patch set (https://lore.kernel.org/linux-efi/20230807025343.1939-2-masahisa.kojima@linaro.org/) proposes to implement SetVariable() in Linux by communicating to said OP-TEE module and letting Linux write to the RPMB partition.